# Stress testing Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I was hoping to get some direction or advice with regards to some trouble I'm having with trying to do some stress testing against a Web API for a client. It is a RESTful WEB API that I'm testing against. I've been creating a list of Tasks that run asynchronously that all call the WEB API but they take a very long time to execute and some just time out. I don't believe that it's throttling the service because I can still call the service in Fiddler on the same machine the test code is running on and it successfully calls the service while the asynchronous tasks are failing so it seems to be an issue with my testing code. Each task creates its own HttpClient and HttpRequestMessage.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not use tools that are made for that? One simple tool that I remember is `WebSurge`

Comment: @ravikumar - thank you. The content of my request is limited to 32775 characters in WebSurge so my XML is being truncated that is being sent. Do you know of another tool I could use that might not have the same limitation or if there's a way around that?

Comment: You might want to take a look at Blazemeter

Comment: I am using **Postman** that is collaboration platform for API development

Comment: @alex - I've tried Postman as well to do the stress testing. I'm able to do some concurrency stress testing using Newman but it doesn't seem to be a legitimate concurrency/stress testing solution from what I can understand. How do you use it to do the concurrency and stress testing if you don't mind me asking? Maybe I'm not using the tool correctly...